# Ways to archive mysql data using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am required to make my application to archive data so that it is possible for a user to select to view data from previous months.

The way I wanted to do it is create an archive table for each table ie. `table_archive`, and use a INSERT SELECT query to insert data to the archive table.
My concern is that the database has over 300 tables, will creating 300 more table affect the speed of my application?

The other requirement is that the user should not be able to change the archive information, how do I lock the table to disable the user to INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE?

Is there any other quicker and easier ways of doing this.

Comment: What is the purpose of the archive?  If it's to keep the database fast and compact, then table partitions might be a better solution.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: The purpose is to enable the user to view information for previous months

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Why are you moving data out to begin with?  Is it because you tables are growing very large?

Comment: My application works like this: the client creates a workshop and the capture data against this workshop, a month later he come and do some changes to this workshop overwriting what he capture the previous month. So what he has requested is the way to archive information for each month.

Comment: Are you thinking a new set of tables for every archive?  I don't think I would do that.  Instead, I would add a column to each table to allow you to track which workshop the data belongs to.  Then you can load a particular workshop and ignore the rest by adding a simple where clause to each of your queries.

Comment: @JoshuaKaiser I have tot of that but it seems difficult to prevent a user from updating the information when I do it like dat

Comment: @JoshuaKaiser, sorry for the late comment. I would like to do something like what you've advised seems its the easiest way for me. But, I would like to ask something, would this solution not affect any speed or performance of the MySQL database? Thanks.

Comment: @xjshiya, That really depends on how many records you are dealing with.  Even it it's many, you can mitigate performance issues by archiving old data, or using a table partitioning strategy.  I'd start with the simple solution and take a look at partitioning if you need more capacity.

Answer (score 0):

600 Tables in a schema shouldn't create a performance issue.  The bigger question is just how much data you are packing into these tables, and how you are forming joins and indexes.  Avoiding writes is easy.  Just revoke the privileges in your new tables.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html

You will want to `grant select` but nothing else to the user that is accessing these.